# For a resx resource file, why should I use an internal or public access modifier?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resx

This might be a dumb question. But I do not understand when the access modifier should be set to *public* and what difference it will make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) level for your projects/solutions if you feel that resource is more likely to be used internally then set it up as a [protected/private/internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) resource, if some of those properties may be configured and accessed by an external solution / project then leave it as public.

Encapsulation is good, just think about the way you consume external libraries and how they expose properties, classes,configurations, that's a good exercise to do. Think like an external developer who doesn't know anything about your project implementation, you can ask yourself the following questions:

- is this piece of code worth to external developers to know about it?
- do I need a pre-configuration on this code?
- is my implementation clear enough so anybody understand it just by looking at the code implementation?
- does the code enforce certain policies/requirements?
- does my code have obscure implementations?

for me for example talking about IOC, setter injection could be a little bit obscure

> Setter injection is just creating a setter property to replace a
>   dependency on a previously instantiated object.  I don’t like Setter
>   Injection because it requires extra, hidden steps to prepare an object
>   to execute

look at [this post](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2005/10/06/the-dependency-injection-pattern-%E2%80%93-what-is-it-and-why-do-i-care/) to get the full context as an example, but again this is just an example.